# Facebook application request doesn't send notofication to users

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

i have a facebook application and i used Facebook Request Dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ in order to send requests.

Everything seems fine, except the notification is not actually sent to the user (i tried with 3 users), though the request is practically from a user to another user.

What can be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you are using the same example, I would `console.log` the response of the callback `requestCallback()` to check for any interesting info.

Comment: what should actually the requestCallback() function do ?

Comment: it'll get called once the invitations are sent. There you can check the response of the request and check for success or errors msgs..etc

Comment: may sound stupid but... where i see the console result? i have done :function requestCallback(response) {

          console.log(response);
      
      } but nothing shows. thanks a lot!

Comment: In Google Chrome, you hit the F12 to open the Developer tools and then click on the Console tab. In Firefox, if you install the Firebug extension (as ALL developers should!) you'll also have that info in the console tab.

Comment: :) i get a weird error : zu is undefined though  i have no zu in my code

Comment: I am checking the console logs, there is no error and it seems to work fine. Never get a notification. I have the same issue.